# Passing parse object between activities

Tags: android, object, android-intent, parse-platform

So I have this Intent that sends a string of a name to another activity. The source of the String is from an object of a class in Parse.

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query1 = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("People");
    query1.getInBackground(objectId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                //success
                String personName = parseObject.getString("personName");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), personName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("personName", personName);
            } else {
                //there is an error
            }
        }
    });
    //push ends
    Intent Go = new Intent(personActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(Go);
```

I have been able to use the code above to get and send a Toast of the person's name into another activity. What I'm trying to do now is to take that person's name string and upload it to parse as a new object in a different class. I've tried using this code which doesn't work.

This is the code in Second Activity that I use to take the String from the Toast and Intent from the Main Activity and send it to Parse as new object in a class.

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    personName = intent.getStringExtra("personName");


    ParseObject newObject = new ParseObject("AnotherPeople");
    newObject.put("peopleName", personName);
    newObject.saveInBackground();
```

This code keeps crashing whenever I try to save the data. Can someone help me please.

Comment: Please post the logs..

Comment: it only says "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity" What does that mean?

Comment: I have provided answer below...that should fix your problem.

Comment: The heading should be 'Pass data; specifically a string between activities?' and not 'Passing Parse objects between activities'. For those who will ask the question around passing Parse objects, Parse Objects implement the Parcelable interface and can be passed from one activity to another using the intent.putExtra("key", "yourParseObject") and retrieved using the intent.getParcelableExtra("key").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not sending the data to the second activity, in the `done()` method you are creating an intent and not using it i.e you are not calling the the `SecondActivity` using `startActivity`.

Outside the `done()` method you are creating another intent and calling the `SecondActivity` but you are not passing the name this time and hence the name is null in the second activity.

Simple fix is, within the done method just call the `startActivity`, so that the data is passed to the SecondActivity.

```
@Override 
    public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) { 
            //success 
            String personName = parseObject.getString("personName");

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), personName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("personName", personName);
           startActivity(intent);  //<----Updated here
        }
```

Comment: WOW!!! IT WORKED!! Thank you so much. I spent 3 days trying to figure this out. I've always wanted to try that solution, but my brain kept telling me "it probably doesn't matter" and ended up never doing it. Thank you again.

Comment: This doesn't pass a parse object. It passes a string.